# What application is alternative to WebTrends?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to tracking of my php system and want to know what people do with my site (like google analytics but i will use for internal system) but I don't have any money to pay for WebTrends. My budget is no more than 500$.

Comment: Seems like if you're alright with the external hits that the included javascript would create, you could use google analytics for this purpose without a lot of issues.

Comment: Try [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/sp/php-monitoring).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Piwik](http://piwik.org), it is an open source analytics platform

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like **http://www.haveamint.com/ would be perfectly suited** to your purpose.

> Mint is an extensible, **self-hosted web site analytics program**. Its interface is an exercise > in simplicity. Visits, referrers, popular pages and searches can all be taken in at a glance > on Mint's flexible dashboard.

If that doesn't fit the bill, have a look at http://piwik.org/ as previously suggested, along with http://www.openwebanalytics.com/.

Even better - **have a look at the [Clicky Analytics competitor comparison table](http://www.getclicky.com/#theotherguys)**, which should give you a good idea of the features of these apps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it has the features you want but [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/) is a more fully-featured analytics tool than Google Analytics.